# Why doesn't it work without bind() in one case and work in another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got two  React Components:
First:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {date: new Date()};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = setInterval( () => this.tick(),1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState({
          date: new Date() 
        });
      }
    
    render() {

        return (
            <div style={{border:"1px solid black"}}> 
                <h1 style={{color:"blue"}}> Component Clock has been rendered </h1>
                <h2> Time: {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

And second:

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

}

  handleClick() {
    
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'On' : 'Off'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

In second component it doesn't work until I bind `handleClick()` to `this`. But it works perfectly in first case, although, I haven't use `bind()`. I can't understand what's the matter =(.
It seems that in first component it automatically captures `this`, how does it happen?

Comment: You don't use the method as a callback in your first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example it only works because you used an arrow function as the `setInterval` callback which bound the `this` of the calling function, `componentDidMount` to be bound to the callback `() => this.tick()` which is the correct expected `this` in the `tick` function when it's called.

In other words, if you had instead done:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
}
```

You'd see the `TypeError: this.setState is not a function` as the component's `this` isn't bound to the inner function.

You could also just bind `this` when passing the callback to `setInterval:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

In the second example the `onClick={this.handleClick}` handler doesn't work until the component's `this` has been bound to the handler. This is done in a few ways:

1. Bound in constructor (*just like the good old days*)

   ```
   class Toggle extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { isToggleOn: true };
       this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); // <-- here
     }

     handleClick() {
       this.setState((prevState) => ({
         isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
       }));
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
           {this.state.isToggleOn ? "On" : "Off"}
         </button>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. Bound when passing callback

   ```
   class Toggle extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { isToggleOn: true };
     }

     handleClick() {
       this.setState((prevState) => ({
         isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
       }));
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}> // <-- here
           {this.state.isToggleOn ? "On" : "Off"}
         </button>
       );
     }
   }
   ```
3. Using arrow function.

   ```
   class Toggle extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { isToggleOn: true };
     }

     handleClick = () => { // <-- here as arrow function
       this.setState((prevState) => ({
         isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
       }));
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
           {this.state.isToggleOn ? "On" : "Off"}
         </button>
       );
     }
   }
   ```